# "Both" "OR" , "Both of "

Tags: grammar

In English , we use " both of " , " both " for two things

for instance , if you are going out for a meal , there are two possible restaurants, you Say :

both restaurants are very good

Or,

both of the restaurants are very good

what is the difference?

Comment: The former is more common in speech. There's no difference in meaning.

Answer (score 1):

You can say:

Both restaurants, both the restaurants and both of the restaurants are all grammatical, without any difference in meaning.  However, the use of both + plural noun (both restaurants) is far more common and idiomatic.